# Get values of hidden fields in controller (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, hidden-field

Can I reach the value of hidden fields in controller action ? And how ? Do I put it in the model somehow ?

Thank you

---

**EDIT:** some code example how to store something in hidden field and retrieve it on postback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hidden fields are just like any other form fields when you get to the POST action being sent to the server.  There's nothing that makes them special outside of their display (or lack thereof, rather) in the browser.  Thus, they should be accessible in much the same way you currently access other form fields.

How do you currently access other form fields?  If they're just mapped to a model which is being passed into the controller action, then hidden fields should be mappable just the same.

Conversely, you should be able to manually access any HTTP POST data from HttpContext and the Request object.

Comment: Yes I do have some forms now. I use `HtmlHelper` methods like `Html.EditorFor` to render properties from model (guess you call it "mapped to model"). I would expect something like `.HiddenFieldForModel` to be there but instead I have found an attribute `HiddenInput` for marking properties. I guess it may do the trick.

Comment: Actually there is `HtmlHelper.HiddenFor` method. Sorry for asking stupid questions...

Comment: @drasto: It's quite alright.  I actually haven't had a lot of experience with the ASP .NET MVC HtmlHelper classes, so we both learned something :)